# Unset the system immutable bit in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, file-management, root, file-attributes

In theory I believe you can unlock and remove the system immutable bit with:

```
chflags noschg /Path/To/File
```

But how can you do this when you've set the bit as root? I have a file that is locked, and even running this command as root will not work as the operation is not permitted.

I tried logging in as Single-User mode to no avail.

I seem to remember that even though you are in as root you are in at level '1'. And to be able to remove the system-immutable flag you need to be logged in at level '0'. Does this have something to do with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to login in with Single-User mode by holding down Command-S

Then

```
mount -uw /
```

and finally:

```
chflags noschg /Path to/File
```